# Vue.js - Loop, fetch and display all data from array.push

Tags: vue.js

I have a button that adds new field with the use of `array.push`. I was able to fetch the right data while using a REST client (Insomnia). I'm aware of how to display the data to a single form using `response => this.item = response.data`, but how do I loop the `response.data` to display all the data entered in the `array.push` fields?

Please see my code below.

**Component.vue**

```
  <template>
    <v-btn @click="addRow()">Add New</v-btn>
  </template>
    <table class="table">
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(row, index) in books" :key="row.id">
          <td>
            <base-select
              v-model="row.book_id"
              :items="books"
              item-text="title" 
              item-value="id" 
              label="Sample Books"
            />
          </td>
          <td><v-textarea label="Title" v-model="row.title" /></td>
          <td><v-textarea label="Genre" v-model="row.genre" /></td>
          <td><v-text-field label="Pages" v-model="row.pages" /></td>
          <td><a @click="removeRow(index);">Remove</a></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

<script>
  export default {
    data: ()=> ({
      books: [],
    }),

    created () {
      this.getBooks ()
    },

    methods: {
      addRow () {
        this.books.push({
          book_id: '',
          title: '',
          genre: '',
          pages: '',
        });
      },
      getBooks () {
        axios.get('/api/books', {
          params: { id: this.$route.params.id }
        })
        .then(response => this.books = // Display all data to each field in row (example there are 3 records existing with the id of params.id) )
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
      },
      removeRow (index) {
        this.buttons.splice(index, 1);
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Screnshot**
I have 5 data in the database and it reflects the number of rows, but the fields are empty.
[image]

Comment: where is this.rows defined

Comment: Sorry about that it was a typo. Thank you for correcting, editing now.

Comment: please change in loop also

Comment: what is the exact issue ?

Comment: I want to fetch all the data and use the `array.push` fields to display the data from the database (`book_id`, `title`, `genre`, `pages`).

Comment: Do you want to update your books array when you do this.books.push ?

Comment: then what's the purpose of array.push if you just want to display the data from the database ?

Comment: If there are data already existing (based on `params.id`) display them in each `array.push` field and at the same time I can still use `array.push` to add additional data.

Comment: then your code is already working, just put this.books = response.data

Comment: Yes all rows has displayed and matched with the number of existing data in the database, but fields are empty. I'll show a screenshot.

Comment: are you sure you are accessing the right variable in the response ?

Comment: are you setting `this.books = response.data` which I cant see in your code ? And can you try console `response.data` and the fields you are mapping

Comment: I have now used the  `this.books = response.data`, I pasted a screenshot after using this. Console gets all the right data, problem is how to display in each field. Sorry guys for bad english.

Comment: the way you accessed the data in loop is okay , the problem is maybe on the response. It doesn't met the data you want to have.

Comment: Yeah. I'll try to still do a workaround on this one, but I really really appreciate your help guys.

Comment: so is it a response.data issue ?

Comment: seems your data properties do not match. So what does `console.log(response.data)` produce?

Comment: It produces an object array (5) and it contains all the data.

Comment: I made it work by making the `v-model` the same name as my database column. Thank you everyone!